# Pandas legend for scatter matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 classes and datapoints of n features.

The following code produces a scatter matrix with histograms in the diagonal, of 4 of the features in the dataframe.

```
colums = ['n1','n2','n3','n4']
grr = pd.scatter_matrix(
dataframe[columns], c=y_train, figsize=(15,15), label=['B','N','O'], marker='.',
    hist_kwds={'bins':20}, s=10, alpha=.8, cmap='brg')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

like this:

[image: Scatter matrix of this dataframe]

The problem I'm having is that plt.legend() doesn't seem to work, it shown no legend at all (or it's the tiny 'le8' barely visible in the first column of the second row...)

What I'd like to have is a single legend that just shows which color is which class.

I've tried all the suggested questions but none have a solution.
I also tried to put the labels in the legend function parameters like this:

```
plt.legend(label=['B','N','O'], loc=1)
```

but to no avail..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I never used `pd.scatter_matrix` to plot scatter matrix plot, but seaborn could be useful if you want. Here an example with legend: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/scatterplot_matrix.html

Comment: This is much easier to produce a scatter matrix plot using seaborn: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pandas `scatter_matrix` is a wrapper for several matplotlib `scatter` plots. Arguments are passed on to the `scatter` function. However, the scatter is usually meant to be used with a colormap and not a legend with discrete labeled points, so there is no argument available to create a legend automatically.

I'm affraid you have to manually create the legend. To this end you may create the dots from the scatter using matplotlib's `plot` function (with empty data) and add them as handles to the legend.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.subplot.right"] = 0.8

v= np.random.rayleigh(size=(30,5))
v[:,4] = np.random.randint(1,4,size=30)/3.
dataframe= pd.DataFrame(v, columns=['n1','n2','n3','n4',"c"])

columns = ['n1','n2','n3','n4']
grr = pd.scatter_matrix(
dataframe[columns], c=dataframe["c"], figsize=(7,5), label=['B','N','O'], marker='.',
    hist_kwds={'bins':20}, s=10, alpha=.8, cmap='brg')

handles = [plt.plot([],[],color=plt.cm.brg(i/2.), ls="", marker=".", \
                    markersize=np.sqrt(10))[0] for i in range(3)]
labels=["Label A", "Label B", "Label C"]
plt.legend(handles, labels, loc=(1.02,0))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As mentionned in ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer. Scatter plots select color from a colormap. However `plt.colorbar()` does not work with `pd.plotting.scatter_matrix`. Here's a simple workaround that consists in plotting an image of the colorbar and labeling it with your target names. Below, I use the iris dataset from sklearn as an example:

```
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

iris = datasets.load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
_ = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, c=iris.target, figsize=[8,8], s=100, alpha=0.8)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow([np.unique(iris.target)])
_ = plt.xticks(ticks=np.unique(iris.target),labels=iris.target_names)
```

Which generates to following figures

[image: scatter matrix]

[image: colorbar]